# UDP server / client in Go not reading data

Tags: udp, go

I have written a UDP server and client in Go.  I am not seeing any error messages when the server is running on `port 1200`, I also do  not see any errors when client is trying to connect to port 1200 on the same machine (OS X 10.9.1)

The server is not printing "SOS...", that is the message the client is writing, in a infinite loop.

The client is able to send a message to the server though, however what the server is reading is 0 bytes.

Server Code

```
package main

import ( "net" "fmt" "time" )

func main() {

        port := "127.0.0.1:1200"

        udpAddress, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp4",port)

        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("error resolving UDP address on ", port)
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
        }

        conn ,err := net.ListenUDP("udp",udpAddress)

        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("error listening on UDP port ", port)
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
        }

        defer conn.Close()

        var buf []byte

        for {

                time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)

                n,address, err := conn.ReadFromUDP(buf)

                if err != nil {
                        fmt.Println("error reading data from connection")
                        fmt.Println(err)
                        return
                }

                if address != nil {

                        fmt.Println("got message from ", address, " with n = ", n)

                        if n > 0 {
                                fmt.Println("from address", address, "got message:", string(buf[0:n]), n)
                        }
                }
        }

}
```

client code, running on same server, with command `go run udp-client.go :1200` or `go run udp-client.go 127.0.0.1:1200`

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"net"
"os"
"time"
)

func main() {

        if len(os.Args) != 2{
                fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Usage:%s host:port", os.Args[0])
                os.Exit(1)
        }

        service := os.Args[1]

        fmt.Println("Connecting to server at ", service)

        conn, err := net.Dial("udp",service)

        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Could not resolve udp address or connect to it  on " , service)
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
        }

        fmt.Println("Connected to server at ", service)

        defer conn.Close()

        fmt.Println("About to write to connection")

        for {

                time.Sleep(1000*time.Millisecond)
                n, err := conn.Write([]byte("SOS ... \n"))
                if err != nil {
                        fmt.Println("error writing data to server", service)
                        fmt.Println(err)
                        return
                }

                if n > 0 {
                        fmt.Println("Wrote ",n, " bytes to server at ", service)
                }
        }

}
```

Comment: Don't have time right now to test or look thoroughly, but you're not checking the errors on conn.Write()

Comment: Yea your right, I have to do a writeUDP from the server with the address of the client, to be able to send the message to the client.  Before that the client needs to send a message to server.  I rewrote the code, and at least the server and client are communicating ,but still no data is being read.  I am able to verify that data is written correctly.

Comment: I have updated the code in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *UDPConn.ReadFromUDP* method reads data and puts it into the slice you provided.
In your case this slice is nil. Therefore your buffer does not provide enough space for data.
You can fix this by changing one line in the server code:

```
var buf []byte = make([]byte, 1500)
```

The buffer size should probably be chosen to fit your network protocol. Or you create a 64k buffer so that you can receive maximum sized udp packets. This however seems a bit wastefull :)